# installing pandas on python - where did numpy go?

Tags: python, excel, url

So I'm trying to open a website/url extract an excel file on the site, edit it, and then put it on a different website. I found another comment on this site that has excellent advice for how to do this using `import pandas`.
I downloaded pandas (and some other modules) from the python website, and wrote the code. But when I try to run it I get the following error

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 626
    .format(openpyxl_compat.start_ver, openpyxl_compat.stop_ver))
UserWarning: Installed openpyxl is not supported at this time. Use >=1.6.1 and <2.0.0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\more_url_stuff.py", line 6, in <module>
    socket = urllib2.urlopen(link)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

What is going on?

Is there an easier way to download the excel file from the internet?

I just started coding with Python last week so I'm still confused with some simple things.

Comment: Take notice of this line: `Warning: Installed openpyxl is not supported at this time. Use >=1.6.1 and <2.0.0.`. What's your version of `openpyxl`?

Comment: Thank you - I'll try to fix that. I wasn't even sure which warning was the one causing all the problems.

Comment: Where do I get an earlier version of openpyxl than 2.0.3 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update:
Pandas 0.15.2 has been released, and it works pretty well with the most current version of openpyxl (2.0 or later). This answer is outdated.

---

OK, it appears that you have obtained the most recent version of pandas (==0.14.0), and this one requires some specific version of the Openpyxl. If you don't care about giving up new features introduced in newer version, try uninstall your existing openpyxl and install an older version.

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
pip install openpyxl==1.8.6
```

If you simply want to download the file and save it to a local folder, here is an easier way:

```
import urllib
URL_to_the_file = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=00&b=29&c=1993&d=05&e=13&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv"
urllib.urlretrieve (URL_to_the_file, "downloaded.csv")
```

Comment: clarification for newbies (like me), the pip ... instructions are executed at an OS shell command, not in a python shell.